# Flutter: how to display a banner when my app is not in foreground (as Maps / Google Map does)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, geolocation

On iOS, when I use Google Maps for an itinerary and I press the home button to show another app, Google map will display a blue banner on top my screen "Google Maps actively uses your location". This banner is permanent, even if I open another application.

My understanding is that this banner allows Google Map to keep receiving location updates and notify the user about it.

How can I achieve the same effect for my Flutter application? For both iOS and android?

Screenshot of the blue banner:

[image: blue banner]

Comment: iOS shows that when an application that doesn't have "always" location permission is using your location in the background. So, if your app has "when in use location permission", and you set background updates on your location manager and call `startUpdatingLocation` the blue indication is shown.

Comment: @Paulw11, Thanks! tell me how to do that in Flutter in an answer? I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Blue banner appears when the app is using your location in the background. The only that it happens is: 1. Location is set to Always, and 2. Your app needs to somehow use the Location in the background.

Comment: Hmm nope. My app use "always" permission and receives notification in background without the banner showing up

Comment: Has your app got a way of using the Location Service in the background?

Comment: Actually, extensive testing yesterday showed that I receive location events only a few minutes after the app is sent to background and then nothing. So I'm looking for a way to run background processes to fetch location in flutter, but oddly I couldn't find any good (i.e. clear to me) documentation on this topic